# populate Wordpress page/post from external db - on the fly

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, .htaccess

After providing an event calender with PHP/MySQL/HTML/CSS I want to use Wordpress for that project from now on. Account and data management will remain outside of wordpress scope.

My best idea so far is to populate the posts (or pages) entirely from the already existing db. The URLs would be created by apache's rewrite engine. 
To use one post and populate just the content would lead to really bad SEO.

So I want to create (virtually) unique posts populated entirely from the db. Extensive research on that topic brought up nothing usable so far. Maybe someone could point me in the right direction?

Preferences:

- using mod rewrite to create the pages urls from event /ID/title rather than using the timestamps to create posts
- keeping the data editable via external admin panel (no copying into WP-DB)
- head data of post / page must be populated from db, e.g. title, author, timestamp etc.

Suggestions would be much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the plugin WP All import. It creates unique post such are car listing etc based on the external DB. I also allows you to style and format your post.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-all-import/

Comment: Thanks for the hint - sadly the plugin only imports data from csv or xml, not directly from a db (same localhost, btw). As I understand it, it is mainly used for product db import. Hope I did not miss the point there...